# Problem using decimal expansion of a number

Tags: decimal-expansion

[image]

Please give me some information about decimal expansion of numbers so that I could try out this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence starts $0,\ 2,\ 4,\ 6,\ 8,\ 20,\ 22\ldots$.

Hint: The sequence contains $5$ numbers less than $10$, $25$ numbers less than $100$, and how many numbers less than $10^n$?

Comment: Please give me some information on decimal expansion before any hints on starting off with the answer.

Comment: What would you like to know about decimal expansion?

Comment: $25$ is the decimal expansion of twenty-five.  $5^2$ is not.  I would have preferred "decimal expression" or "usual expression"

Comment: @Servaes I would like to know about writing the decimal expansion of a number. What type of restriction rise up whwn it is given that the decimal expansion should only include 0,2,4,6,8.

Comment: Precisely the restriction that is given; that the decimal expansion should only include $0,2,4,6,8$. For example, the number $8642$ has only even digits, whereas $8641$ does not. This is all you need to know to solve the problem.

Comment: But how to find the nth term in terms of n? After that I could substitute for it in the given equation and use L-Hospital rule to find the limit.

Comment: The $n$-th term of the sequence is the quinary expansion of $n$ viewed as a decimal expansion, multiplied by two. As far as I know it is not (easily) expressable in a way that extends to a differentiable function on $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$. I would advise against trying to use L'Hôpital's rule. In stead, try using the squeeze theorem.